# how to make element of navbar always visible on resize?

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar that contains a div, i need to do it like [instagram.com](https://www.instagram.com/) that when i resize the window; the inside element stays always visible.

Is there a certain strategy in CSS to do the same thing?

CSS:

```
.navbar {
   position: fixed;
   background-color: #039D6E;
   width:100%;
   height: 55px;
   white-space: nowrap;
}


.subNav{ /* Inside Div of the navbar that always need to be visible */
  height:55px;
  width:auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left:25%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give .subNav a fixed width, for example `width: 150px;`.

See test fiddle below:

```css
.navbar {
   position: fixed;
   background-color: #039D6E;
   width:100%;
   height: 55px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
}


.subNav{ /* Inside Div of the navbar that always need to be visible */
  height: 51px;
  width: 150px;
  resize:none;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
  left:25%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  //padding: 12px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
<div class="subNav">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it worked , 
but subnav contains items inside of it and while resizing not all of them will appear , 
is there a way to make the div and it's components visible

Comment: Please share some example code that shows your problem.